# Minecraft - run with more ram?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried to make minecraft run with more ram, but when I edit the arguments it seems that it can't create enough ram even for 2G. I have almost 4G of ram  usable though.
arguments: -Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M

Comment: Can you post the argument(s) that you are using the increase the ram?

Comment: Also keep in mind that these arguments are more of a max than an explicitly defined usage, the argument tells the JVM to preallocate that much memory, but it is very possible Minecraft itself won't ever reach that level.

Comment: @Phaeze added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the JVM arguments you are using I don't think there would be a problem.
As I stated in my comment, the `Xmx` argument is a maximum setting and will only ever be reached if Minecraft has enough chunks loaded, so to put it simply having a higher `Xmx` value will allow to have a higher render distance set in game (this is an extreme over simplification).

That being said there is an additional option you can specify that will allow you to tell the JVM to allocate that memory immediately, rather than as needed; the option looks like `-Xms2G`. However this will only provide a very minimal performance increase if any at all.

I would also try removing the `Xmn` argument, this setting is used for things in memory that are short lived and it will likely be cutting into the 2G overall max (don't quote me on that I could be wrong)

I am not too knowledgeable on the other JVM arguments you have specified but I did find [this article](http://www.streambase.com/developers/docs/latest/admin/garbagecollection.html) that mentions to avoid using both `UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` and `CMSIncrementalMode` and that `UseConcMarkSweepGc` and `UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` are contradictory settings

A quick final note, if you are trying to get Minecraft to use more ram to improve performance, it is much more likely that your processor or video card are performance bottlenecks here than your ram. I especially think this because you are already providing it with more memory than it is using.